# Best Buy API tradeInValue is blank

Tags: best-buy-api

```
http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products((type=Game))?format=xml&show=name,sku,platform,salePrice,tradeInValue&pageSize=100&apiKey=MYKEYGOESHERE
```

I used to run this code with in Excel to return a list of all video games, their sale price, and trade in value. However, the trade in value attribute is now blank. Did Best Buy stop providing this information for some reason? Is there an alternative means of getting this information?

I did a query for Grand Theft Auto V, a new game that one would definitely be able to trade in, and still there was no trade in value listed; just a blank space next to the trade in value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trade In Values is not something that is provided in the API anymore, at least for the time being. We were finding issues with stale/inaccurate data from our source and so, until we can find a more stable source of information, we are excluding that attribute.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: any more news on this?